# How to pop to previous scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created 2 scenes in storyboard and 1 xib file.I have put 2 buttons in xib file( button1 to go to first scene and button2 to go to 2nd scene).From first scene if I move to second scene and from there to third scene(xib file) and if I click on button1,it navigates properly(i.e.,to first scene) and If I click on button2,it comes back to second scene.It works properly.But instead from first scene if I move directly to third scene(xib file) and now if I click button2,it comes back to first scene only.But I wanted it to come to second scene.Button1 works properly,but not button2.So can anyone help me out in this?I want button2 to work as I said.

My code for that is:

```
@implementation XYZGreenViewController
-(IBAction)goredscreen:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}

-(IBAction)goBlueScreen:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: First tell us which IBAction is handle by button1 and which one is handled by button2.

Comment: Full confusion in your explanation. Just give short explanation. Here all are developers. They can understand....

Comment: The question is very much confused. We can understand in better terms.

Answer (score 1):

Think of UINavigationController as a stack, every time you navigate to a new scene/ViewController, you are essentially pushing a new view controller to your stack.

In your first scenario, you have the following in your stacks once you arrived at the third scene

```
[first scene | second scene | third scene]
```

If you press on any of the button for that matter, you will pop out the third scene and go back to the second scene.

In the second case, you went directly from first scene to the third scene then you will have the following in your stack

```
[first scene | third scene]
```

Obviously, if you popout a viewcontroller then it will back to the first scene because the second scene was never on the stack. However, you can push it into the stack by using `pushViewController:`

Comment: Will you please tell how to do that?

Comment: You cannot pop back into second scene because you never navigated to it. You can use self.navigationer pushViewController:SecondSceneVC in order to go to second scene

Answer (score 0):

Here in this poptoviewcontroller will not work in this scenario.  first of all you have to import the class which you push to view controller.
SecondViewController.h
-(void)btn2clicked:(id)sender{
      SecondViewcontroller *Objsecond = [[Secondviewcontroller alloc]initwithNibName:@"Secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationcontroller pushtoviewcontroller:Objsecond animated:yes];
you can use like this..

Comment: Secondviewcontroller used by me is storyboard but not xib..so if I use the code given above, it gives this error-  No visible @interface for "secondviewcontroller" declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'